# Residue of $f(z) = z^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need to find the residue of $f(z) = z^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ at $z = 0$

I did the following:

$\sin (w)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}w^{2n+1}$ $\implies$
$\sin\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\frac1{z^{4n+2}}$

$\implies f(z) = z^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\frac1{z^{4n}} = 1-\frac{1}{6}z^{-4}+\frac{1}{120}z^{-8}-+...$

Now what do I do?

Comment: You are already done. What is the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$ term in that expansion?

Comment: 0. So 0 is my residue?
Shouldn't I be looking for the coefficient of $z^{-2}$ (which is 0 again)?

Comment: $0$ is your residue. And no, you shouldn't, because the definition of residue is the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$ term.

Comment: alright, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(z) = \sin z/z$. It has removable singularity at $0$, so it has Laurent series $$g(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2+\ldots$$ on the punctured plane $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. Then $$f(z) = g(1/z^2) = a_0 + a_1z^{-2} + \ldots$$ on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ and thus the residue is $0$.